# Dockerfile (docker container) sudo password error

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, permissions, sudo

I faced some troubles dealing with sudo inside docker container.

First of all: my goal is to execute several commands at the start of docker container (CMD line) which requires root privileges. **There is no problem** when you execute them under default root container user. But I want to create the different user with root privileges and execute same commands using him.

Here is my dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu

WORKDIR /app

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive 

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install postgresql python3-pip

#installing sudo 

RUN apt-get install sudo 

COPY requirements.txt .

COPY . .

#creating admin

RUN useradd -g sudo -G postgres -p 123 testadmin

WORKDIR /var/run/

RUN chmod 777 postgresql && chown testadmin:postgres postgresql

USER testadmin

WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 8000

#CMD sh /app/entrypoint.sh
```

Container successfully builds up. I have superuser "testadmin" selected with password "123".

Then I`m entering container cli and trying to execute folowing command:

`sudo service postgresql start`  **again, it requires root previleges**

System asks for password. When I type "123" and enter it says "Sorry, try again".

I have no idea why it`s happening.

I`m new to docker and linux and I understand that my containers build approach is bad. Im doing this for educational purposes. Im looking for solution only using DOCKEFILE and not docker-compose even though it`s easier. May you please help me to create user with root privileges and execute all of my commands using him?

1. I`ve tried to get rid of password completely. Sudo still requires a password for some reason.

Comment: A container normally runs only one process; normal practice would be to split the database into a separate container.  In normal use you should not need to "enter the container CLI" at all, and you shouldn't ever need `sudo`.

Comment: If the user has sudo access, wouldn't an attacker that compromises the container as that user also have sudo access to root?